# Show hidden div in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, show, hidden

I have this countdown timer, and once it reaches 0, I want it to show div, which is currently set to: `display: none;`

Here is the countdown code:

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
      var timer = duration,
          minutes, seconds;
      setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + " min " + seconds + " sec";

        if (--timer < 0) {
            display.textContent = "Yay, It's done!"

      }

      }, 1000);
    }

    window.onload = function () {
          display1 = document.querySelector('#time1');

      startTimer(1 * 5, display1);
    };
```

At this part:

```
if (--timer < 0) {
    display.textContent = "Yay, It's done!"
```

how would I make it also show hidden div, after showing that text?

Comment: Set the CSS to `display: block;`

Comment: add style to your `display` element (make it visible) i.e. `display.style.display = "block";`

Answer (score 1):

You would set its display to block.

```
elementYouWantToShow.style.display = 'block';
```

Answer (score 1):

Plain JS

```
document.getElementById('myID').style.display = "block";
```

JQuery

```
$('#myID').fadeIn();
```